# cannot launch node of type : can't locate node in package ERROR: cannot launch node of type : can't locate node in package

Tags: ros, frontier-exploration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when i launch the launch file of the `frontier_exploration` package provided by ros.org i recieve the following error:

```
 cannot launch node of type [frontier_exploration/explore_client]: can't locate node [explore_client] in package [frontier_exploration]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [frontier_exploration/explore_server]: can't locate node [explore_server] in package [frontier_exploration]
```

help! plz

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223384/cannot-launch-node-of-type-:-can%27t-locate-node-in-package-error:-cannot-launch-node-of-type-:-can%27t-locate-node-in-package/) by [naqi.nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/25464/naqi.nick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2016-01-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [naqi.nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/25464/naqi.nick/) on 2016-01-02**:
the nodes are there inside the package but i dont know why it is showing such behavior

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-01-02**:
Please update your question with how you installed ROS, which version, which tutorial you followed, how you installed the `frontier_exploration` package, how you setup your workspace, etc, etc. How do you expect us to help you without that information?

**Comment by [naqi.nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/25464/naqi.nick/) on 2016-01-03**:
http://wiki.ros.org/frontier_exploration i took the package available on this web address.
i am using ros jade.
installed it step by step as explained on ROS.ORG

**Comment by [naqi.nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/25464/naqi.nick/) on 2016-01-03**:
i dont know why cant it find the file explore_client it is right inside the src folder of the package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

there was a problem with my ROS Jade i reinstalled it and i started working properly

---

Originally posted by [naqi.nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/25464/naqi.nick/) with karma: 62 on 2016-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0